# Relationship of Two Dimensional Joint PDF and it's Conditional PDF

Tags: probability

I am having some trouble with the intuition behind conditional PDFs. For example consider a 2-d normal distribution that is the joint PDF over the sample spaces x and y. If I am interested in the conditional pdf f(x|y) at a given y (Y for instance), is it appropriate to consider the slice of the 2-d plot at Y (scaled so it integrates to 1) as the conditional PDF at a that value of y?

Comment: yes. Note $\displaystyle f_{X|Y=y}(x|y) = \frac {f_{X,Y}(x,y)} {f_Y(y)}$ and this is a function of $x$. So the numerator is the "slice" and the denominator is the scaling factor.

Comment: I understand that $$ \displaystyle f_{X|Y=y}(x|y) $$ should be a function of x only. How can we be sure that $$ \displaystyle  \frac {f_{X,Y}(x,y)} {f_Y(y)}  $$ is a function of x only. In general $$ \displaystyle  \frac {f(x,y)} {g(y)}  $$ is a function of both x and y

Comment: The $y$ is "fixed" so I say it is a function of $x$. Of course the equation holds for all $y$ in the support.